# $http.get and $templateCache

Tags: angularjs, caching

Could someone explain to me the following code:

```
$http.get('./template.html', {
    cache: $templateCache
}).then (function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

I understand `response.data` will be equal to the whole content of template.html, however what about the object

```
{cache: $templateCache}
```

**What does it do?**

Comment: Did you read documentation about $http? *"cache – {boolean|Object} – A boolean value or object created with $cacheFactory to enable or disable caching of the HTTP response. See $http Caching for more information."*. So you say, use `$templateCache` to cache HTML template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a line from documentation for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service:

> **cache** – `{boolean|Object}` – A boolean value or object created with [`$cacheFactory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) to enable or disable caching of the HTTP response. See [$http Caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) for more information.

So by specifying `{cache: $templateCache}` you tell Angular to cache HTTP response in internal cache data map, accessible as [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) service. It means that if you request `./template.html` again with `$http.get` or by using template as source in `ngInclude` directive, it will not be redownloaded but will be retrieved from cache.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`$templateCache` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache):

> The first time a template is used, it is loaded in the template cache
>   for quick retrieval. You can load templates directly into the cache in
>   a `script` tag, or by consuming the `$templateCache` service directly.

It means the response will be stored in cache. In terms of perf, it is interesting as you won't load the template again when refreshing the page.